# How to use std::bind with the standard library and save the return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, bind

I'm working on a class that schedules functions by binding them in a queue like this:

```
std::queue <void()> q;

template<typename R,typename... ArgsT>
        void
        schedule(R& fn, ArgsT&... args)
        {
            q.push(std::bind(fn, std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...) );
        };

template<typename R,typename... ArgsT>
        void
        schedule(R&& fn, ArgsT&&... args)
        {
            q.push(std::bind(fn, std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...) );
        };
```

As you see I made the type in the `queue` `void()` to make it hold any type of function objects but now I can't get the return when I execute it. What should I do to solve this?

Note: I don't want to use an external library like boost and I don't know what kind of function the user will pass it.

Comment: What do you expect to do with the return value if you don't know the type?

Comment: There is `std::any` in C++17, or `boost::any`. But it seems like you don't want to use either of them.

Comment: @Kevin  this is part of class schedules functions in a queue and execute them concurrently  and the user can get the return later after the function execution done  so I want some how to save it to get it by a std::future and return it to the user

Comment: @Rakete1111  I will take a look on std::any but is there any better solution?

Comment: @mohabmohamed The only other solution I know of is having a common base class to every object returned, sorry...

Comment: Return a future of an appropriate type.

Comment: You don't need to overload `schedule`. The `R&& fn, ArgsT&&... args` one covers everything correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: I don't want to use an external library like boost and I don't
>   know what's the kind of function the user will pass it.

What I usually do in this case is I use a base class (from Command pattern) in my queue, and then have two implementations, the one wrapping the bind, and the other (also wrapping the bind) exposing a function that allows getting the return value.

Here is an example of the returning specialization (at last):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>


struct ACmd
{
  virtual void exec() = 0;
  virtual ~ACmd(){}
};

template <class F>
struct Cmd;

template <class R, class ... Args>
struct Cmd<R(Args...)> : ACmd
{
  R result_;
  std::function<R()> func_;

  template <class F>
  Cmd(F&& func, Args&&... args): result_(), func_()
  {
    auto f = std::bind(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    func_ = [f](){
      return f();
    };
  }

  virtual void exec(){
    result_ = func_();
  }

  const R& getResult() const {return result_;}
};

// Make function for convenience, could return by value or ptr - 
//  - your choice
template <class R, class F, class ...Args>
Cmd<R(Args...)>* cmd(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
  return new Cmd<R(Args...)>(func, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//... And overload for void...

int foo(int arg) {
  return arg;   
}

int main() {

  auto x = cmd<int>(foo, 10);
  x->exec();
  std::cout << x->getResult() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of the execution of each element in the `queue`, it is `void`, you have already defined it as such. If the functions passed in are required to return a value, then you would need to limit the type(s) returned to a fixed type, use utilities such as `std::any`, `std::variant` or some covariant types (possible with a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`).

The simplest is to fix the return type (at compile time);

```
template <typename R>
using MQ = std::queue<std::function<R()>>;

MQ<int> q;
```

See the sample below.

---

The queue declaration needs to be a `queue` of objects, such as [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects. The return value from a `bind` can be assigned to a `function` and then used as expected.

`std::function` is a polymorphic function wrapper, it implements type erasure patterns akin to `any`, but is specifically designed for functions and other callable objects.

By way of [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a7f8bd34552e4c5);

```
template <typename R>
using MQ = std::queue<std::function<R()>>;

MQ<int> q;

template<typename R,typename... ArgsT>
        void
        schedule(R&& fn, ArgsT&&... args)
        {
            q.push(std::bind(std::forward<R>(fn), std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...) );
        };

int main()
{   
    schedule([](int a) { std::cout << "function called" << std::endl; return a; }, 42);

    std::cout << q.front()() << std::endl;
}
```